# Show two decimal places if decimal part is greater than 0 in angular 7

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

I am working on an Angular 7 application. How to format the numbers as below:

```
2.14569 to 2.14
3.245 to 3.24
1.00 to 1
```

How can i achieve this in Angular. I have tried (| number:'1.2-2') this but it always give two decimal places like 4.00 but i want it to be 4. Basically my problem is that, if there is decimal part and that is greater than 0 then show only two decimal places otherwise just show simple number without decimal part.

Comment: look at this link https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe

Comment: {{decimalValue | number:'1.0-2'}} try this

Comment: There is a small change, what if i have to show only one decimal part ? @DeepshikhaChaudhary. What should be the expression then ?

Comment: You mean like 2.14569 to 2.1 this?

Comment: Yes,@DeepshikhaChaudhary. and 2.0000 to 2

Comment: number:'1.0-1', this is not working @DeepshikhaChaudhary, its still giving 2 decimals

Comment: `{{decimalValue.one | number:'1.0-1'}}` this should be the expression when you want to show only one digit after the decimal place. And for 2.0000 should work fine without any pipe.

Comment: Its not working, the type of my value on which i am applying this conversion is number, there is no decimal type in angular @DeepshikhaChaudhary

Comment: Please provide your code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193877/discussion-between-waleed-naveed-and-deepshikha-chaudhary).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    // Data 
decimalValue = {
        one: 2.14569,
        two: 3.245,
        three: 1.00
      }

// HTML
    <div>{{decimalValue.one | number:'1.0-2'}}</div>
    <div>{{decimalValue.two | number:'1.0-2'}}</div>
    <div>{{decimalValue.three | number:'1.0-2'}}</div>
```

Comment: There is no need for that (one, two, three) after decimalValue @Deepshikha Chaudhary